# How to create pages in the footer in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have installed magento1.8.0.1, and also import sample data.

I added one more menus,

Now i want add pages like e-mail us, so i go to cms -> pages -> add new page ->. so it will be created, i want to know how to display that e-mail us page in footer.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!!!.

Comment: Display the page or the link of that page in footer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various way, but for your quick reference:

1. Go to Magento Admin
2. Go to CMS Block
3. Edit Footer Links (Click on that name)

Do whatever changes you like and save that page.

Good luck!

Comment: Sure, do accept this answer and post new questions for related products

Comment: yea, but better to start separate thread for new questions and accept the questions which has got right answer. This will keep SO clean and help community

Comment: Accept this my answer by click on on Right Sign, and start new question.

Comment: You really have to start new question to get the right answer. But if you insist, I suggest you to go reference http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page. See under "All Products from one Category" heading. Note: This guidelines is for editing home page, You have to be editing your Kitchenware page

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503348/how-to-add-products-under-submenu-in-magento